# Firebase get key value

Tags: javascript, firebase

It's easy to get value:

```
    firebase_instance.limit(100).on("child_added", function(data) {
        var value = data.val();
    });
```

but how to get a key associated with that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of your Firebase `.on(...)` callbacks are going to be invoked with a Firebase [DataSnapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/index.html). To get the name for the location of that DataSnapshot, try using the [name()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/name.html) method.

For example:

```
firebase_instance.limit(100).on("child_added", function(snap) {
  var name = snap.name();
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Use **key** property

```
firebase_instance.limit(100).on("child_added", function(snap) {
  var name = snap.key;
});
```

Documentation and examples [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)